# How can I override bootstraps default of 767px to display my menu?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7. by default the Hamburger menu doesn't display until the screen width reaches 767px. I need to get similar behaviour happening sooner.

For my purposes the following css will give me my initial result in displaying the hamburger menu :

```
@media (max-width: 1197px) {    
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: -16px;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right : 0px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.navbar-brand {
    width:auto;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin: -1px -15px !important;
    margin-bottom: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
}
```

The issue I have now though is that when I press the 'hamburger' button to display the menu. It display's for a split second and then disappears.

When I toggle the hamburger in a manner that I expect to see the menu, my div item with the class navbar-collapse has the expected classes of collapse and 'in' attached but display has been set to 'none' as opposed to 'block' when I debug through chrome. I can see that the display has been set by bootstrap.css.
I have tried setting the display style in the bootstrap 'shown.bs.collapse' event and I can see when debugging my code is hit, but bootstrap.css still overrides this, even when I attach '!important' to the display. Am I missing a further event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a specific media query for this, from your question, below 768px, the navbar will collapse, so apply it above 768px and below 1000px, just like that:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
       .collapse {
           display: none !important;
       }
    }
```

This will hide the navbar collapse until the default occurrence of the bootstrap unit. As the collapse class flips the inner assets inside navbar collapse will be automatically hidden, like wise you have to set your css as you desired design.

Comment: You can see from my css that I already have this in my style. It seems that the `@media  (min-width: 768px)' of bootstrap.css is overriding mine. For debate I'm at a width 900px. If I remove it from my CSS and use your example setting `max-width:1197px` I still get the same issue

Comment: Doh! just needed to add  `.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { display: block; }` in the @media css